# IBM MobileFirst Platform ClassPath error during installation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Running MFPF7.0.0.0-IF201506081356 on WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.5 (that's 8.5.5 with fp 5 applied), IBM Java 7.0.8.10.

After deploying the first runtime to server the following error occurs:

```
6/10/15 15:25:05:600 CEST] 0000002c com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               E SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Failed to load listener: com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.worklight.server.bundle.api.WorklightBundles
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:308)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:252)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ParentLastClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:81)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:373)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:764)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:749)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass0(UnifiedClassLoader.java:106)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader$Delegation.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:77)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:101)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ThreadContextClassLoader.loadClass(ThreadContextClassLoader.java:108)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:726)
        at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:283)
        at com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:116)`enter code here`
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it means that the worklight-jee-library.jar shared library referenced in the server.xml (in each MFP runtime application) is not found. Check the path of this library in the server.xml and that the jar file is present in this path.